# NEXTJS Web api deployment on NGINX Server Issue : index.html missing on my dist folder after the build

Tags: nginx, npm, next.js

When i run the command npm run build i got 2 folders (dist and node_modules).
I think it is the dist folder i have to put on the /usr/share/nginx/html directory to make it available.

But my question is : is it normal to not have an index.html file on my dist ? how to make it accessible to the user from my nginx server without any index.html file

Comment: Are you deploying your Next.js app as [static HTML](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export)? If so, you need to run `next build && next export` and get the static files from the `out` folder.